# Determining linesize= and pagesize= in SAS that correspond to specific margins?

Tags: sas

I am printing to file using

```
file print titles linesleft = 10 pagesize = 40 linesize = 120;
```

in a `data _null_` procecdure.

I am using default font/font size.  My question is how to determine what to set `linesize=` and `pagesize=` to so that I can obtain specific margins, say 1'' all around for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  I'd run screaming into the hills if MY_WORKPLACE asked me to do that.  Use ODS, for heaven's sake.

Comment: Perhaps look at the various MARGIN options - OPTION LEFTMARGIN=1in; etc.

Comment: @Joe Yeah me too! But I'm sure there's plenty of reasons that require that kind of coding.  I once had to modify our cheque printing program when we changed the blank cheque paper size.  That wasn't in SAS but I'm sure there's plenty of other scenarios that may require it.  What if the files are to be displayed on a fixed width terminal screen somehow... idk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you're using Windows and SAS 9.x.  (Similar reports can be generated for Unix and Mainframe systems, but you may not have specific control over all the options.  Check your system first -- i.e., PROC OPTIONS.)

Set-up your environment first.  Under File, the Page Setup option is used to set orientation (portrait or landscape) and the margins you want.  Then under File, the Print Setup option allows you to select the font you want.  Once the font is selected, you can see the linesize and pagesize settings on the Print Setup box for the selected font.  Set your OPTIONS statement on your program to reflect the linesize, pagesize, margins, orientation, and font to the Page Setup and Print Setup boxes.

Recommendation -- don't use a proportional font, but use a fixed width font like Courier New or SAS Monospace Bold.  Proporitonal fonts screw-up your column alignments.  Also, if you're sending this report to a non-SAS user, you should probably skip using the SAS  Monospace font and use Courier or New Courier fonts.  Their machine probably wouldn't have the SAS Monospace type font installed.  Thus when the report is opened for viewing, they have to substitute in a different font as well which could also screw up your column alignment.

Recommendation -- layout your output file using Word or other text editor with the appropriate font and margins you're going to use for your report.  Put in column markers often to check your report layout.

Now you can write the code in your data *null* step.  Be sure to use the header and the lines left options on the FILE statement so you can appropriately layout headers and footers on your document.  Remember to use the RETURN statement at the end of both the header area and footer area as well as the end of the report area code.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for advice.  So I checked margins, line size, page size and font were being used, and I set options accordingly, however my output is out of whack with the line size and page size it lists in print setup.  Print setput gives a linesize=95 and pagesize=33.  With these settings my output is not displayed correctly.  I changed my sizes to much larger, ls=150 and ps=45, and my output looks good.  Also, I am outputing to a pdf `(ods pdf; ... ods pdf close;)`.  Should I be worried?